# what the hook for displaying course list page for learndash plugin?

Tags: plugins, hooks

I installed LearnDash plugin into my local wordpress, and I want to change the course list page from pic A to Pic B. My idea is to use add_filter() function to rewrite the course list page, using the course list data and write my custom view for it. However,I couldn't find which functions are for course list page. Anyone can help me?

Pic A:
[image]

Pic B:
[image]